# Button dentro de DataList no realiza ninguna acción

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, aplicación-web, asp

Tengo una datalist que contiene labels para mostrar nombre, precio, descripcion, etc de multiples producto y un botón dentro del datalist para tomar el ID del producto y redireccionarlo a otra pagina:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_agregar" runat="server" Text="Agregar" OnClick="Btn_agregar_Click" />
```

A este botón le agregué las propiedades: `CommandName="addtocart"` y `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID_producto") %>'` y el datalist tiene la siguiente acción:

```
protected void DataProducto_ItemCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "addtocart")
        {
            Response.Redirect("cart.aspx?id=" + 
            e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        }
    }
```

no marca error, pero tampoco realiza acción. Sospecho que es porque el evento `Button_click` no contiene ninguna acción, sin embargo, no se como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Si en el evento click no tienes nada asignado es muy probable que sea eso, intenta llamar el método `DataProducto_ItemCommand` dentro del evento `Btn_agregar_Click`

Comment: Gracias, intenté hacer eso, pero me marca error. Llamé el método como DataProducto_ItemCommand(); y no funcionó. ¿Qué parámetros requiere? porque parece que ese es el error. Ni object source ni  DataListCommandEventArgs e me los acepta.